# Unable to give min and max value to "UIProgressView" in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview

I am using `UIProgressView` to show percentage

so i have taken progressview in storyboard and given its class as `UIProgressView`

**here if i give any value to `percentageView.progress =` its totally filling.. it should fill only the given value, `how to fill percentageView with given value?`**

*these are the attribute inspector values in storyboard for `UIProgressView`*

[image]

code:

```
class CandidateDashboardVC: UIViewController{

var progressValue : Float = 0

@IBOutlet weak var percentageView: UIProgressView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
// percentageView.progress = 75.00 

}
}
```

o/p: `var progressValue : Float = 0` then

[image]

o/p: if i give `percentageView.progress = 75.00` in didload then.. **it should fill only 75% of progress but it is totally filling, why?** please do guide.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percentages are represented as a float from 0 to 1.

Not from 0 to 100.

So, 75% is 0.75.

If you set it to 0.75 you will see the progress you want.

In your calculation just divide by 100. (Or, don’t multiply by 100 in the first place).

This is explained in the docs… https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprogressview/1619844-progress

Comment: I am getting progress value from backend like 74 as Int, so i have tried like this
`percentageView.progress = Float(data.user?.percentage ?? 0).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 100)`
then o/p
`progress value 1.0 test float value  74.0`

Comment: how do i get 74 as 0.74.. please guide me

Comment: Simply `Float(data.user?.percentage ?? 0)/100`

Answer (score 0):

if someone is looking for similar try below solution

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
formatter.roundingMode = .down
            
progressView.progress += 0.01
lblTimer.text = formatter.string(from: progressView.progress * 100 as NSNumber)
progressView.setProgress(progressView.progress, animated: true)
if(progressView.progress == 10.0){
    progressBarTimer.invalidate()
    isRunning = false
    buttonView.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
}
```